# How can I submit scores with one decimal to Game Center?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, game-center

I want to send my score with one decimal to Game Center. Ho can I do this??

Answer (score 0):

You can only submit 64 bit integers as scores to a leaderboard. From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html):

> To Game Center, a score is just a
>   64-bit integer value reported by your
>   application. You are free to decide
>   what a score means, and how your
>   application calculates it. When you
>   are ready to add the leaderboard to
>   your application, you configure
>   leaderboards on iTunes Connect to tell
>   Game Center how a score should be
>   formatted and displayed to the player.
>   Further, you provide localized strings
>   so that the scores can be displayed
>   correctly in different languages. A
>   key advantage of configuring
>   leaderboards in iTunes Connect is that
>   the Game Center application can show
>   your game’s scores without you having
>   to write any code.

That doc page should tell you about formatting your score. It sounds like in order to display float-like scores you will have to tinker with the format settings in iTunes Connect.

Try this :

```
- (IBAction)setScore 
{      
     float score = (float)self.currentScore / 100.0f;
     currentScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", score]; 
     NSLog(@"%lld", self.currentScore);
}
```